# Parse a File using Bash

Tags: bash, parsing

I have a file with multiple lines of Data that looks like this:

```
{date=2017-01-01 time=23:59:59 logid=0000000001 srcip=123.123.123.123 srcport=2222 srcintf="Branches_Out" dstip=222.222.222.222 dstport=80 service="tcp/8080" appid=41469 app="Microsoft.Portal" apprisk=elevated applist="default"
date=2017-01-01 time=24:00:00 logid=0000000002 srcip=124.124.124.124 srcport=3333 srcintf="Branches_Out" dstip=111.111.111.111 dstport=90 service="tcp/9090" appid=15893 app="HTTP.BROWSER" apprisk=elevated applist="default"}
```

For each line I need a Bash code to look for specific Data values after `(srcip=, dstip=, dstport=, service=, app=)` and parse it into new file, new file should look like this:

```
{123.123.123.123, 222.222.222.222, 80, tcp/8080, "Microsoft.Portal"
124.124.124.124, 111.111.111.111, 90, tcp/9090, "HTTP.BROWSER"}
```

note that line sizes may vary i.e. some lines may contain more fields, other lines may not contain all fields i.e. may not contain `app=`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In awk:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {                                           # in the beginning
    split("srcip dstip dstport service app",t)    # form wanted keyword list
    for(i in t)
        a[t[i]]
}
{
    for((i=1)&&b="";i<=NF;i++) {                  # check every field
        split($i,k,"=")                           # split on =
        if(k[1] in a)                             # if in keyword list
            b=b (b==""?(NR==1?"{":"\n"):OFS) k[2] # append to buffer
    } 
    printf "%s", b                                # output buffer
}
END {
    print "}"                                     # sugar on the top
}' file
{123.123.123.123 222.222.222.222 80 "tcp/8080" "Microsoft.Portal"
124.124.124.124 111.111.111.111 90 "tcp/9090" "HTTP.BROWSER"}
```

Comment: error with line: b=b (b==""?(NR==1?"{":"\n"):OFS) k[2]

Comment: What is the error? Looking at it `"\n"` should be replaced with `ORS`.

Comment: awk: cmd. line:11: Call to undefined function

Comment: Then you're missing a space before a `(`; it's trying to call non-existent function `b()` or `?()`.

Comment: Thanx A lot its working like magic, I've ran it on another System and its running fine

Answer (score 0):

Save following script as, say, `script.sh`

```
$ cat script.sh

#!/usr/bin/env bash
# add all the keys you need to extract here
keys=(srcip dstip dstport service app)
output=""
while read line; do
    newline=""
    for opt in ${keys[@]}; do
        val="$(echo "$line" | sed -n "s/.*${opt}=\(\S*\).*/\1/p;")"
        if ! [[ -z $val ]]; then
            newline+="$val, "
        fi
    done
    if ! [[ -z $newline ]]; then
        output+="${newline::-2}\n"
    fi  
done <file
if [[ -z $output ]]; then
    echo "nothing extracted!"
    exit 1
fi
echo -e "{${output::-2}}" > extracted.txt
```

input file content:

```
$ cat input.txt

{date=2017-01-01 time=23:59:59 logid=0000000001 srcip=123.123.123.123 srcport=2222 srcintf="Branches_Out" dstip=222.222.222.222 dstport=80 service="tcp/8080" appid=41469 app="Microsoft.Portal" apprisk=elevated applist="default"
date=2017-01-01 time=24:00:00 logid=0000000002 srcip=124.124.124.124 srcport=3333 srcintf="Branches_Out" dstip=111.111.111.111 dstport=90 service="tcp/9090" appid=15893 app="HTTP.BROWSER" apprisk=elevated applist="default"}
```

execute the script providing input file as the first argument:

```
$ bash script.sh input.txt
```

This will generate the output file `extracted.txt` in the working directory.

output file content:

```
$ cat extracted.txt

{123.123.123.123, 222.222.222.222, 80, "tcp/8080", "Microsoft.Portal"
124.124.124.124, 111.111.111.111, 90, "tcp/9090", "HTTP.BROWSER"}
```

Comment: didn't work, seems val="$(echo "$line" | sed -n "s/.*${opt}=\(\S*\).*/\1/p;")" isn't correct

Comment: Probably you are doing something wrong. I've updated the answer with step by step details. If the issue persists, provide exact details about the error you are getting.

Comment: Working fine, Thanx a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you are attempting several different ways. Sticking to a simple `grep -Po` to separate the wanted values into `label=value` format and then piping the `label=value` lines to a `while read` loop controlling `IFS` by adding an `=` as a separator, then allows you to use a simple counter (counting to `5` for your `5-terms`), you can format them as you have shown.

A simply script putting that altogether could be:

```
#!/bin/bash

fname="$1"

test -r "$fname" || {  ## validate filename is readable
    printf "error: file not readable.\nusage: %s filename\n" "${0//*\//}"
    exit 1
}

## use grep -Po to parse into label=value lines
grep -Po 'srcip=[0-9]+[.][0-9]+[.][0-9]+[.][0-9]+|dstip=[0-9]+[.][0-9]+[.][0-9]+[.][0-9]+|dstport=[0-9]+|service="([a-z]+/[0-9]+)"|app="([A-Za-z]+[.][A-Za-z]+)"' "$fname" | 
{
    beg=0
    cnt=0  ## use read with IFS and a counter to parse into CSV
    while IFS="$IFS=" read -r label value; do 
        [ "$beg" -eq '1' ] && [ "$cnt" -eq '0' ] && printf "\n"
        [ "$beg" -eq '0' ] && [ "$cnt" -eq '0' ] && { beg=1; printf "{"; }
        [ "$cnt" -eq '4' ] && printf "%s" "$value" || printf "%s, " "${value//\"/}"

        ((cnt++))
        ((cnt == 5)) && cnt=0
    done
    printf "}\n"
}
```

**Input File**

All on one line, but shown here separated,

```
$ cat zz
{date=2017-01-01 time=23:59:59 logid=0000000001 srcip=123.123.123.123 srcport=2222 
srcintf="Branches_Out" dstip=222.222.222.222 dstport=80 service="tcp/8080" 
appid=41469 app="Microsoft.Portal" apprisk=elevated applist="default" 
date=2017-01-01 time=24:00:00 logid=0000000002 srcip=124.124.124.124 srcport=3333
srcintf="Branches_Out" dstip=111.111.111.111 dstport=90 service="tcp/9090" 
appid=15893 app="HTTP.BROWSER" apprisk=elevated applist="default"}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ bash parselog.sh zz
{123.123.123.123, 222.222.222.222, 80, tcp/8080, "Microsoft.Portal"
124.124.124.124, 111.111.111.111, 90, tcp/9090, "HTTP.BROWSER"}
```

Look things over and let me know if this is close to what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: It works fine if all lines has the same format terms (5) at the same order, but how to make it work if lines aren't static, i.e. lines may or may not contain all 5 terms, also terms may not be at the same order.

Comment: That becomes a different problem. It can be done, but you must include another loop, and read your input *word-by-word*. (or dynamically build your regex from a variable set of terms) Then in a separate loop scan each word against your set of regular expression to check for a match. If a match is found, you can add it to an array that is unset at the beginning of each line (therefore only holds the matches found per-line) After scanning each word in the line, you can then write the contents of the array out in CSV format (handling a variable number of terms)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Perl Regex to match the whole pattern.

```
 Pattern='{date=(.*?) time=(.*?) logid=(.*?) srcip=(.*?) srcport=(.*?) srcintf=(.*?) dstip=(.*?) dstport=(.*?) service=(.*?) appid=(.*?) app=(.*?) apprisk=(.*?) applist=(.*?)';
```

Then while displaying you can replace the match characters using match numbers $1,$2...)

```
perl -spe 'print s/$Pattern/{$4, $7, $8, $9, $11}/g'  <filename>
```

You need to add other match numbers in the substitution.